# How can I add a custom legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, legend

I have a following code for my ggplot in which some countries have same colour in horizontal bar chart.

```
p <- ggplot(sample, aes(x = reorder(sample$Country, sample$size), y = sample$size,fill = sample$Country, 
    label = sample$size )) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    ggpubr::rotate_x_text() + 
    coord_flip() + 
    geom_text(hjust = -0.1)+ 
    theme(legend.position = "none") + 
    scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("United States" = "#00CCFF", "India" = "#33FF00", "China" = 
    "#FFFF00", "Germany" = "#000099", "Russia" = "#CC0000", "Japan" = "#FF66CC","France" ="#666600", 
    "United Kingdom" = "#00CCFF", "Italy" = "#FF9933", "Brazil" = "#FFFF00", "Spain" = "#993300", "Iran" 
    = "orange", "Mexico" = "#003333","Poland" = "#33FF00", "Turkey" = "orange", "Indonesia" = 
     "#FFFF00","Saudi Arabia" = "#00CCFF", "NetherLands" = "#993300", "Canada" = "#666600"))
```

[image: Original Plot]

How can I code a custom legend like this in ggplot?

[image: Needed Custom Legend]

[image]

Comment: try removing all `sample$` from your aes call

Comment: I have updated the post to make it more clear.